# How can I check whether the device is connected to bluetooth or not in react native?

Tags: react-native, npm

I'm creating an app in that checking the mobile is connected to any Bluetooth enabled device if it's connected then I want to perform some action.

I've tried many libraries listed below

1. react-native-ble-manager
2. react-native-ble-plx
3. react-native-bluetooth-serial
4. react-native-bluetooth-serial-next
   etc..

None of these libraries are providing whether the device is connected or not. 
If they have method isConnected, they always return false if the device is connected or not. For testing, I'm using a bluetooth headset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `react-native-netinfo`, also.

https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-netinfo

```
NetInfo.getConnectionInfo().then(data => {
  console.log("Connection type", data.type);
  console.log("Connection effective type", data.effectiveType);
});
```

you can check whether the `data.type` is **bluetooth** or not. (Only works on android)

Answer (score 0):

Using react-native-ble-plx you can add a listener to the bluetooth state:

```
const subscription = manager.onStateChange((state) => {
    console.log("Bluetooth state: ", state);
    if (state == 'PoweredOn') {
        perform_bluetooth_operations();
    }
}, true);


perform_bluetooth_operations () {
    // this is where you will begin bluetooth operations.
}
```

This answer will work with both ios and android.