# Stop a function after a time if it doesn't work

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a function that allows to connect to external devices using bluetooth.

Sometimes that could be the case in which external devices are off, or the device couldn't be found, 
So my app crashes on the search page (it hangs on a load). I would like to know if there is a method to send an alert after 30 seconds in which the function has been executed.

```
   async scans() {
//connection...
// if the connection failed the checkCredentials will not execute, so there I should find something to display alert.
        this.checkCredentials()
    }
```

I have thought to a `setTimeout(() => {this.setState({time: true})}, 15000)`

but I'm not sure that it is the best solution.

How can I do??

Comment: You should probably try to handle the connection errors themselves rather than use a timeout. This post might be of use - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55866641/how-can-i-check-whether-the-device-is-connected-to-bluetooth-or-not-in-react-nat

Comment: The problem is that there isn't an error but only a block for example because the device are off.

Comment: if you're already dealing with promises, you could just `Promise.race()` your connecting code against a timeout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should first try to check if the device exists or not before initiating the connection. Then as a next step you should handle the connection error. You can check if connection API provides a way to supply the timeout. If none of this is possible then only you should try to handle this by using setTimeout as you have mentioned in your question. However in this case you should also consider the scenario to cancel the connection request or atleast handle the error when the connection eventually fails.

Answer (score 0):

in case that you want to wait for some specific seconds. You can use setTimeout(). But if you want to wait after a connection response a better solution could be that you use try catch block that if the connection failed you can handle it